# Should quantitative predictors be transformed  to be normally distributed?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, normality-assumption, predictor, glmm

I am always struggling with normality testing for quantitative predictors (no factors) and transforming them to normality.

- If I am running a GLMM and my predictors are really non-normal, should I  transform them as well to try to make them normally distributed?
- I know that this is important for the response variable but what should be done with predictors?

P.S.: I really could not find a similar question.

Comment: There are *loads* of threads on exactly this subject.  Follow the `data-transformation` tag.

Comment: @whuber, I think once I read your response to this indeed FAQ, but I have not found the thread :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is nothing in the theory behind regression models that requires any distribution for X other than having a minimum number of observations in each range of X for which you want to learn something.  The only problem you usually run into is overly influential observations due to a heavy right tail of the distribution of X.  To deal with that I often fit something like a restricted cubic spline in the cube root or square root of X.  In the R **rms** package this would look like `y ~ rcs(x^(1/3)) + ...` other variables or `rcs(sqrt(x),5) + ...` (5=5 knots using default knot placement).  That way you only assume a smooth relationship but you limit the influence of large values, while allowing for zeros (though not negative values).

Comment: many thanks! in my case the predictors are not that awfully right tailed. but good to know that rms exists. thanks for sharing your approach.