# Interpreting odds ratios with log-transformed continuous variables in a logistic regression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, logistic, predictor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interpretation of log transformed predictors in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8318/interpretation-of-log-transformed-predictors-in-logistic-regression)
>   [Should quantitative predictors be transformed  to be normally distributed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12715/should-quantitative-predictors-be-transformed-to-be-normally-distributed)

I was hoping for some general advice. I am using STATA to undertake a binary logistic regression with several independent variables. Most of these are categorical except for one which is a continuous variable. I have already found that this variable is not normally distributed and so I have log10 transformed it. In my regression analysis I have used the log transformed values of the continuous and get an odds ratio of 3. However, I am struggling how to interpret this value in terms of the outcome (disease or not disease).

Any thoughts or advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks